# Integrating Fody NotifyPropertyChanged in MvvmCross

Tags: mvvmcross, fody

What is the correct way of integrating Fody with MvvmCross? Do I need any special plumbing code or configuration to ensure that the correct `RaisePropertyChanged` in class `MvxNotifyPropertyChanged` is getting called?

Comment: Could you explain a bit about what you have tried? Did you try reading: http://twincoders.com/blog/codigo-limpio-con-fody/ ?

Comment: Even though I don't understand the language, I can tell the article is not complete since it did not specify the attribute on the class. Just because the article is there does not mean it's complete.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do anything special. If you define a viewmodel as follows:

`public class HomeViewModel : MvxViewModel { ... }`

It should just work.

Edited:

As described here https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/wiki/Options

> Note: For most tool-kits you actually do not need to set EventInvokerNames as the default covers most common tool-kits.

is `RaisePropertyChanged` supported by default, which as you can see in the `MvxNotifyPropertyChanged` class is what's being used by [MvvmCross](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/1ec7bc5f0307595c7ae11f56727dd0e9d2a2262f/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/ViewModels/MvxNotifyPropertyChanged.cs#L40).

Comment: Yeah I did go through this, and it says that RaisePropertyChanged is in the default list of methods Fody will search. However since Mvx is not in the list of supported platforms, I wanted to confirm that I don't need to do anything. I can tell it is working, but for some reason when I set a breakpoint in MvxNotifyPropertyChanged class it's not hitting.

Comment: Can you verify with a reflector tool (such as .NET Reflector or JetBrains dotPeek) that when you open up the compiled assembly, the calls to `RaisePropertyChanged(...)` are actually emitted within the assembly? (and as such verify that Fody is run correctly upon compiling)

Comment: not sure if I can do that on xamarin platform, can I?

Comment: I just found out [sample code](https://github.com/slodge/BindingTalk/blob/master/BindingTalk.Droid/ViewModels/FodySimpleViewModel.cs) from Mvx that uses Fody

Comment: In short: yes you can use it with Xamarin.

Fody is a IL Weaver tool and it runs as part of the compilation process, it then changes the IL that's emitted within the output assembly. So after compilation the assembly that is generated is no different than any other .NET assembly, and as such can be used within Xamarin (or mono in particular)

Answer (score 0):

One quick cent that took me ages to figure out; very unlikely someone else would have the same problem, but still.

Fody does work perfectly, however, on mac, if the source files are in FAT32 drive, builder gives an error.

note: I also had a FodyWeavers.xml with following settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Weavers>
  <PropertyChanged EventInvokerNames="RaisePropertyChanged" />
</Weavers>
```

That worked flawlessly with mvvmCross; but recently I moved back to backing field with no fody; makes me feel better.

Comment: As noted by the `Optional. Defaults to "OnPropertyChanged, NotifyOfPropertyChange, RaisePropertyChanged, NotifyPropertyChanged, NotifyChanged"` note on the following [page](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/wiki/Options), you don't need the `EventInvokerNames="RaisePropertyChanged"` attribute on the PropertyChanged element.

Comment: Stephan, is that from the latest versions? I originally implemented it back in January, and I am almost sure it was needed then.

Comment: I'm not certain from which version this is no longer required.